# Why select query executes none in Python where as in MYSQL it has a value returned?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to select a header for a UDP packet stored on a MYSQL database but when I execute the query in python the query is none. But running the query directly on navicat it does return the value I want.
Code:

```
  INFO_conn = mysql.connector.connect (host = "IP_ADDRESS",
                                    user = "USERNAME",
                                    passwd = "PASSWORD")
  INFO_cursor = INFO_conn.cursor (mysql.connector.cursor)
  query = "SELECT HEX(DATA) from TABLE  LIMIT 1"
  result = INFO_cursor.execute(query)
```

Result is always none. Assume that all server information above is correct.

I assume the information is too big for either the cursor or results. The variable is not defined before this. I have tried selecting the data as binary, chars, and just directly without converting it. The only time the query had a result was when I didn't convert it. But it returned the maximum integer value for a 64 byte integer.

Comment: `LD2_conn` should be `INFO_conn`, and `LD2_cursor` should be `INFO_cursor`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that, one sec. In the real code the variable names match

Comment: Just to make sure: how are you using "result"? (In other words: could you add the next line(s) of your code?) "result" will be an iterator (or false), not the value for `hex(data)` itself. You will have to fetch the value using the iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was trying to access a iterator, to access the information within the cursor after I execute the query I have to call the .fetchall() method.

```
INFO_conn = mysql.connector.connect (host = "IP_ADDRESS",
                                user = "USERNAME",
                                passwd = "PASSWORD")
INFO_cursor = INFO_conn.cursor (mysql.connector.cursor)
query = "SELECT HEX(DATA) from TABLE  LIMIT 1"
INFO_cursor.execute(query)
results = INFO_cursor.fetchall()
```

Results now contains the Hex information I was looking for.